# How to do Real time data synchronization between windows forms and remote server

Tags: c#, signalr, real-time, microsoft-sync-framework

[image: Flow]

My scenario is as shown in the above image. Here customer and shop will be using a windows form application and there is local DB for both. 
For example if customer checks for shops products and place order, it will store in local DB of customer and then push it to central server, from there particular shop should get the order details notification. similarly if order is approved, the data should be updated in central server as well as it should push to customer local DB as update.

we tried using SignalR For this, based on this article [Is it correct to use SignalR for desktop applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261987/is-it-correct-to-use-signalr-for-desktop-applications?answertab=active#tab-top)  there is no direct support of signalR for windows Forms.

what about using [Microsoft Sync Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854(v=sql.110).aspx) for this, will it be fine and do the job for me?

So is there any other technique to implement real time data sync in c# windows forms.

Comment: Why not just write a centralized wcf service with a database and be done with it?

Comment: Indeed, why bother with sync and local DB, when you can store data only in central server and implement API/WCF calls to the central server? I mean what is the purpose of having local DB?

Comment: "real time" is an empty shell if you don't fill it with explicit constraints.

Comment: you both are right @trailmax and TheGeneral, but the purpose of having local DB is the particular application should also work offline, because it has many other features other than ordering.

Comment: @ArjunJS So sync will not be "real-time" then (if client is offline no sync happens). Perhaps a bit more explanation of your architecture in your question will help to draw better answers.

Comment: Your question seems too broad to me and it's difficult to formulate a specific answer. Having dealt with database synchronization in many projects, I would suggest you get a deeper understanding of some important concepts before choosing one tool or the other. Recently I've written an article on this subject: https://medium.com/@adolfomarinucci/data-synchronization-primer-88ad04e1747b and a .net standard library that could be useful in your case: https://github.com/adospace/CoreSync

Comment: My advice would be to give a try to a sync framework, like Dotmim.Sync : https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync  (doc : https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago,

I faced this problem and find out a solution. I hope you can get idea from my solution.

I called an api for transferring data(json) between shop to server and server to shop.
I used same database structure for shop and server, Just added one extra field named shop_id to server and build up an composite primary key to server.

When needs to sync, user will press sync buttons then code will check the is_sync false data and send that data to api

```
Table structure:
       id,....,is_sync

Interactions:
   Shop->Server
   Server->Shop
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering this after almost an year but it might help someone else.

I recently worked on similar requirement. There are few libraries which could be helpful for this.

1. [SocketIO4Net](https://github.com/jstott/socketio4net)
2. [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet)

I used SocketIoClientDotNet and it is porting of javascript library [Socket.IO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io), so it is very easy to integrate it. It is working great in my project but now it is deprecated. Still, you can use it as last version is very stable and there are very few open issues.